# Can the numbers $2^m 3^n$ have an infinitely long arithmetic sequence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am asking for proof the set $ \{ 1,2,4,8,\dots \} \times \{1,3,9,27,\dots \} = \{1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,\dots \}$ does not have infinitely long arithmetic sequences inside.  This is OEIS [A036561](https://oeis.org/A036561).

What if we allow for more prime factors $\{2^a 3^b 5^c: a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}\}$ ?

---

One possibility is to let $X = 2^\mathbb{N} \times 3^\mathbb{N}$ and check that $X \cap [1,n]$ does not have enough elements as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The natural density of all Hamming-type families is $0$, so none contains an infinitely long arithmetic progression, since an infinite arithmetic progression has natural density $\frac{1}{d}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, is the question equivalent to the following?

Let $a_0,b_0,d$ be constant, and integer. Is the equation $$2^{a_0}3^{b_0}+nd=2^a3^b $$ satisfied for all $n$ by a pair of integers $a,b$ respectively$\ge a_0,b_0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Assume contrariwise that such sequences existed. Let $s,s+r,s+2r,s+3r,\ldots$  be the one with minimal $s$. If $\gcd(s,r)>1$ then both $s$ and $r$ are divisible by $p\in\{2,3\}$. Then the sequence $s/p,s/p+r/p,s/p+2r/p,\ldots$ would be another sequence violating the minimality of $s$.

Therefore $\gcd(s,r)=1$. But then Dirichlet's theorem tells us that there are infinitely many prime numbers in that sequence.

Comment: Sorry to invoke Dirichlet here. Density arguments need less machinery :-/

Comment: See it's not so easy? Dirichlet's theorem was my motivation for this problem.  As for the comments above, proving the natural density is 0 might also be hard.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think this is a more elegant argument that a density argument, but that is just my opinion.